# Error when creating gcp vm instance via terraform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, virtual-machine, terraform-provider-gcp

service account has all permission to create an vm instance (Service Account User, Project Owner, Project Editor). When I run terraform, this occurs:

```
│ Error: Error waiting for instance to create: The user does not have access to service account 'mymail@gmail.com'.  User: 'terraform@direct-keel-275713.iam.gserviceaccount.com'.  Ask a project owner to grant you the iam.serviceAccountUser role on the service account
│ 
│ 
│   with module.vm.google_compute_instance.icinga,
│   on modules/vm/main.tf line 23, in resource "google_compute_instance" "icinga":
│   23: resource "google_compute_instance" "icinga" {
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

There is something wrong with how you have Terraform setup.

The error message includes the text ***The user does not have access to service account 'mymail@gmail.com'.***

The identity **mymail@gmail.com** is not a service account.

Once you have the credentials set up correctly, the identity that Terraform is using for authorization must have the role **roles/iam.serviceAccountUser** or similar. The role you select must have the permission **iam.serviceAccounts.actAs**.

[Service Accounts Roles](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-roles#service-accounts-roles)

Note: roles such as **roles/compute.admin** do not have the permission **iam.serviceAccounts.actAs**.

Terraform by default will look for the environment variable **GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS**. That variable should point to the full path of a service account JSON key file.

Next, Terraform will look for the CLI/SDK credentials created by **gcloud auth application-default login**.

I prefer to specify the service account in the Terraform HCL (usually in a variables file).

```
provider "google" {
  project = "PROJECT_ID"
  credentials = "/path/to/service-account.json"
}
```

Comment: This reference doc tells you what predefined roles contain what permissions: https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/permissions-reference